# Stellar core log: idle timeout and connectHandler error: Operation aborted

Tags: stellar-core, error

Is this normal? How do I fix?

```
2019-03-15T19:55:53.368 GDDAN [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=22945300, prev=a60b85, tx_count=20, sv: [  txH: f5976e, ct: 1552679752, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2019-03-15T19:55:53.373 GDDAN [Tx INFO] applying ledger 22945300 (txs:20, ops:119)
2019-03-15T19:55:53.740 GDDAN [Ledger INFO] Closed ledger: [seq=22945300, hash=72ea38]
2019-03-15T19:55:54.259 GDDAN [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 182.232.185.189:11625
2019-03-15T19:55:56.259 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING] idle timeout
2019-03-15T19:55:56.262 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING]  connectHandler error: Operation aborted.
2019-03-15T19:55:57.264 GDDAN [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 54.195.8.71:11625
2019-03-15T19:55:57.270 GDDAN [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 54.78.213.232:11625
2019-03-15T19:55:58.543 GDDAN [Herder INFO] Quorum information for 22945299 : {"agree":5,"delayed":0,"disagree":0,"fail_at":2,"hash":"ba2fc8","missing":0,"phase":"EXTERNALIZE"}

2019-03-15T19:55:58.550 GDDAN [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=22945301, prev=72ea38, tx_count=19, sv: [  txH: 0eeb91, ct: 1552679757, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2019-03-15T19:55:58.554 GDDAN [Tx INFO] applying ledger 22945301 (txs:19, ops:27)
2019-03-15T19:55:58.688 GDDAN [Ledger INFO] Closed ledger: [seq=22945301, hash=f627ab]
2019-03-15T19:55:59.264 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING] idle timeout
2019-03-15T19:55:59.267 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING]  connectHandler error: Operation aborted.
2019-03-15T19:55:59.269 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING] idle timeout
2019-03-15T19:55:59.270 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING]  connectHandler error: Operation aborted.
2019-03-15T19:56:00.275 GDDAN [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 54.217.155.123:11625
2019-03-15T19:56:02.276 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING] idle timeout
2019-03-15T19:56:02.278 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING]  connectHandler error: Operation aborted.
2019-03-15T19:56:03.644 GDDAN [Herder INFO] Quorum information for 22945300 : {"agree":5,"delayed":0,"disagree":0,"fail_at":2,"hash":"ba2fc8","missing":0,"phase":"EXTERNALIZE"}

2019-03-15T19:56:03.652 GDDAN [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=22945302, prev=f627ab, tx_count=23, sv: [  txH: da1631, ct: 1552679762, upgrades: [ ] ]]
2019-03-15T19:56:03.656 GDDAN [Tx INFO] applying ledger 22945302 (txs:23, ops:44)
2019-03-15T19:56:03.941 GDDAN [Ledger INFO] Closed ledger: [seq=22945302, hash=e707bd]
2019-03-15T19:56:06.285 GDDAN [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 35.197.60.160:11625
2019-03-15T19:56:06.290 GDDAN [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 59.33.100.41:11625
2019-03-15T19:56:08.285 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING] idle timeout
2019-03-15T19:56:08.288 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING]  connectHandler error: Operation aborted.
2019-03-15T19:56:08.289 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING] idle timeout
2019-03-15T19:56:08.290 GDDAN [Overlay WARNING]  connectHandler error: Operation aborted.
2019-03-15T19:56:09.301 GDDAN [Overlay INFO] New connected peer 35.239.16.180:11625
2019-03-15T19:56:09.502 GDDAN [Herder INFO] Quorum information for 22945301 : {"agree":5,"delayed":0,"disagree":0,"fail_at":2,"hash":"ba2fc8","missing":0,"phase":"EXTERNALIZE"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just connection failures from/to some other nodes, you can safely ignore them if your node works fine otherwise.

You can find out if your node is basically well connected to the network by looking at its connected peers via `curl localhost:11626/peers`. You should be connected to at least 8 (default config: TARGET_PEER_CONNECTIONS) other nodes.